# How open default terminal instead of using `xterm` ? is it safe to use ${TERM}?

Tags: bash, xterm, gentoo

I want to run steam on linux, and I don't want to install xterm, there are two moments when does it want xterm

```
echo -e "$*" >$tmpfile
xterm -T "$title" -e "cat $tmpfile; echo -n 'Press enter to continue: '; read input"
rm -f $tmpfile
```

and

```
# Fall back to sudo in a terminal
xterm -e sudo -p "$prompt
[sudo] password for user: " $*
```

is it safe for posix to use ${TERM} instead of xterm here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the script will be running in an X session; no, there is no reason to believe that `TERM` will be set under those circumstances (and if it is, it would be a coincidence for it to point to a binary of the same name -- the contents of this variable should be a key for Termcap or Terminfo; a lot of the time, on modern systems, it might be something like `vt220` if it's not some variant of `xterm`, or `emacs` or `dumb`).

On the other hand, if your environment is X, you are basically guaranteed to have `xterm`.

Debian defines `x-terminal-program` (IIRC) to let the user or system administrator pick a different default terminal emulator.

I don't think POSIX 1003 has any concept of the problem you are attempting to solve (and we are guessing, too; perhaps you could add more details to your question?)

A better platform to require users to have available might be Freedesktop.org but I have no idea whether e.g. Mac OSX adheres to any useful subset of that. (They might implement all if it; I simply don't know.)

On the other hand, the simple, crude fix would be to require the script to be run from a terminal in the first place; then, you can simply use `cat` to display text files (your EULA, I would guess?) and `echo` (or `cat` again) and `read` to interact with the user. That is, don't attempt to open a new terminal window for these things. Maybe do all interaction near the beginning of the script to make it easy to bail out early.

If you want graphical interaction, you need to limit your target platform, or write complex wrapping for each different environment.

Comment: no, I have no xterm, do you think I must add xterm as package depend of steam?

Comment: If your target platform is really e.g. Debian or Red hat then you should mention that in the question. You have asked about POSIX which implies portability across SunOS, Windows NT (painfully), Linux, Mac OSX, etc. Anyway, added a couple of additional paragraphs to the answer.

Comment: I see, my target platform is gentoo )